# How do I implement external js file in html webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I created the following JS in an external file:

```
var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1); {
   window.alert(n);  
    if (n) 
      var output = "";
      if (n % 3 == 0)
        output += "Rock";
      if (n % 5 == 0)
        output += "star";
      window.alert(output || n); }
```

I want to implement this code when a person clicks a button on the webpage.

Would I use need to place this into my html page: Click me?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to put this code in a function, and then bind the click event of your button to execute that function.

For the function, something like:

```
function rockstar() {
    ... your code ...
}
```

The call `rockstar()` when your button is clicked.

Comment: So change var n to function (n) = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);?

Answer (score 0):

Create an external file Rockstar.js.
Add a Funktion:

```
function rockstar() {
var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1); 
console.log(n);  
if (n) 
  var output = "";
if (n % 3 == 0)
  output += "Rock";
if (n % 5 == 0)
  output += "star";
console.log(output, n); 
}
```

now add it to  or  section inyour HTML with

```
<script src=" Rockstar.js "></script>
```

you can bind rockstar() to an onclick event or call in a script Tag from here.

hope this helps

edit: use console.log instead of alert. alert causes all function to halt.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, my second, window.alert isn't showing up.  I changed it to the following: function rockstar() {
  var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1); {
   window.alert(n);  
    if (n) 
      var output = "";
      if (n % 3 == 0)
        output += "Rock";
      if (n % 5 == 0)
        output += "Star";
      window.alert(output || n); }
    }

Comment: use console.log ;) or change it to window.alert(output+' '+n). try it in devtools, works fine.

and remove the { after the var declaration the } after the function.